# Script for Adding dots at the End of some Directories

Tags: bash, rename

Let's suppose I have a Directoriy whis structure:

```
Divulgation
├── Biology
│   └── Dawkins, C Richard
│       └── Books
├── Chemistry
│   └── Gray, Theodore W
│       └── Books
└── Physics
    ├── Hawking, Stephen W
    │   └── Books
    └── Sagan, Carl E
        └── Books
```

and I want to add dots at the end of the Initials, like this:

```
Divulgation
├── Biology
│   └── Dawkins, C. Richard
│       └── Books
├── Chemistry
│   └── Gray, Theodore W.
│       └── Books
└── Physics
    ├── Hawking, Stephen W.
    │   └── Books
    └── Sagan, Carl E.
        └── Books
```

To remove them, it can be something like this:

```
shopt -s extglob  
shopt -s globstar 
for d in @(Divulgation)/**/*./    
do echo "mv \"$d\" \"${d%./}/\" " 
         mv "$d" "${d%./}/" 
done
```

But, to add them, I don't know .. Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple initials? Are they separated by spaces? (`White, T H` or `White, TH`)

Comment: good point, let's suppose .. umm T H .. I like dots too .. but when you open the hard disk on windows .. and it ends with a dot .. well, is not possible to open the folder .. Blame Microsoft for this question .. and blame the people who use Windows instead of Linux

Comment: If you have `sed`, you can do something like: `dest=$(echo "$d" | sed ':a; s/\(.* \)\([A-Z]\) /\1\2. /; ta'); mv "$d" "$dest"`. Note that you should remove the traliing `/` from the destination, or your `mv` will fail (`mv a b/` attempts to move `a` inside `b`, giving `b/a` and not `b`)

Comment: What about non-Western single-letter names? (I suppose you could still add the dot and call it the abbreviation too, lol)

Comment: Are there Single-Letter Names? I had no idea

Comment: Yes, there are. For instance, `O` is a family name (in French speaking countries). For instance, the politician [Cédric O](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9dric_O).

Comment: @DieDauphin : It seems that Koreans living abroad also transscribe their family name [with a single `O`., and `U` and `I`](https://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2660&context=wordways)  also seem to occur isolated sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

`BASH_REMATCH` is your friend:

Here a solution for the case that you have only one middle initial. Repeat this in a loop if you want to catch all of them:

```
if [[ $d =~ (.*\ [A-Z])($|\ .*) ]]
then
  new_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

After a regexp match, bash populates the array BASH_REMATCH with the capture-groups of the regexp. The first group captures everything up to a space followed by an upper case letter, and the second group captures the rest, and also makes sure that there either was a space after the letter as well, or that it was the last letter. With other words: Makes sure that it was indeed an isolated letter.